# USB C-type hub HDMI weird colour

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, usb-c

I recently bought a USB-C hub to be able to connect all my desktop devices (including a monitor) to my laptop at once (plus wired internet).

It works great, but I immediately noticed that since I'm using USB-C to connect the monitor to the laptop instead of HDMI the monitor's colours are much worse than when I was using the HDMI output - everything appears to have 'less colour', like a grey filter has been put on the screen. The problem persists with extended display, mirror and only using the external display as well - but not on Windows on the same laptop, so it must be a software issue. The built-in display is unaffected.

I tried searching the web but only found old threads with even weirder colour changes, or display outs not working at all. Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

This solution has worked for me:

```
xrandr --output DP-2 --set "Broadcast RGB" "Full"
```

You need to put your output from `DP-2` to the proper value for your display if it is different from mine. You can check all your outputs by simply runnning `xrandr` in the Terminal.